# Godot Input.is_action_pressed not working

Tags: godot, gdscript

Im trying to make a basic endless runner, however my character wont jump,
Code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

#movement speed
const SPEED = 200
const GRAVITY = 10
const JUMP_POWER = -250
const FLOOR = Vector2(0, -1)

var velocity = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.x = SPEED

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui-up"):
        velocity.y = -250
        print("jumped")
    velocity.y += GRAVITY

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, FLOOR)
```

The character moves right continuously like he's supposed to and gravity works fine. Even if i remove the condition: `if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui-up"):` the jump mechanic works and the character floats. As well as this, I have removed `velocity.x = SPEED` to see if that was the problem and it wasn't. I've checked the input map to ensure that space and the up arrow key are binded to "ui-up" and they both are. No errors occur so the only thing i can think of is that the condition for some reason is never True. I'm really confused as to why this isn't working and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely source of your problem is the combination of _physics_process and is_action_just_pressed. _physics_process is not guaranteed to be called every frame and so it can easily miss the action.

A better solution would be to catch the jump in _input, store the information about the jump in a script-level variable and then look at this variable in _physics_process.

Comment: Thanks! It's now detecting the input but kinda messed everything else up but I'll do some more research and get it working. I have been looking for a solution for hours so thanks a lot for the help :)